# Crash proof regex?

Tags: c++, c, regex, crash

I have been using the standard UNIX version of regex in several servers that have to be very resilient to errors. Over the years I have found several cases where either a malformed regular expression has been input by a user or some weird characters in the target string have caused a segmentation violation etc. which crashes the server. For our systems this is unacceptable.

Is there a version of regex around that in these malformed patterns or match string will only result in an error and not crash the server?

As this code is mostly multi threaded when these patterns are being checked I don't want to use setjmp longjmp etc.

Comment: `malformed regex` - compile the regex and check for exception `some weird characters in the string` - how do you clean the input? And how does the server "crashes"? Is it software? Or the whole OS?

Comment: I'd guess that you can expect `std::basic_regex` and related to be pretty robust.

Comment: @Angew: Not if the user enters `^(x*x*)*$` as his regex and lets it loose on `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker: Good example where the regex engine is used for DDOS

Comment: The defense against bad regex is to set timeout and kill the thread when it takes too long to match.

Comment: @nhahtdh - the whole server process crashes not the OS.

Comment: @Angew - i would have expented that std:basic_regex is just a rapper around posix regex but its worth a check.

Comment: @nhahtdh - never really has a regex that goes on and on and never returns but interesting to know a solution.

Comment: @Asad - thanks for the corrections to my question.

Comment: @DavidAllanFinch: It will **eventually** return. Can be a few hundred years later :P And if the server process crashes - check whether it is caused by 1) unhandled exception 2) regex that takes very long to return

Comment: @nhahtdh - malformed regex: I am now doing some some level of sanity checking of patterns and input string but you can only do this once you have figured out the patterns. IE counting "(" and ")" if they don't balance there can be problem. So you need to check the result of the reg compilier.

Comment: @nhahtdh - there are no exception, the code is compiled for historical reason with them switched off. The one I am working on crashed in __regexec_C and I don't even know the signal that causes this, it is on a machine on the other-side of the world I don't have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is C++ regex library [`RE2`](http://code.google.com/p/re2/) developed by Google originally for Go language, but now has wrappers for most scripting languages like Perl, Python, which claims:

> RE2 uses automata theory to guarantee that regular expression searches
>   run in time linear in the size of the input. RE2 implements memory
>   limits, so that searches can be constrained to a fixed amount of
>   memory. RE2 is engineered to use a small fixed C++ stack footprint no
>   matter what inputs or regular expressions it must process; thus RE2 is
>   useful in multithreaded environments where thread stacks cannot grow
>   arbitrarily large.

So, it seems like pick any three: fast, reliable, small.